# Pandas finding intervals (of n-Days) and capturing start/end dates

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

This started its life as a list of activities. I first built a matrix similar to the one below to represent all activities, which I inverted to show all inactivity, before building the following matrix, where zero indicates an activity, and anything greater than zero indicates the number of days before the next activity.

```
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Item | 01/08/2020 | 02/08/2020 | 03/08/2020 | 04/08/2020 | 05/08/2020 | 06/08/2020 | 07/08/2020 | 08/08/2020 | 09/08/2020 |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| A    |          0 |          0 |          0 |          0 |          0 |          0 |          0 |          0 |          0 |
| B    |          3 |          2 |          1 |          0 |          0 |          3 |          2 |          1 |          0 |
| C    |          0 |          2 |          1 |          0 |          1 |          0 |          0 |          0 |          0 |
| D    |          7 |          6 |          5 |          4 |          3 |          2 |          1 |          0 |          0 |
| E    |         11 |         10 |          9 |          8 |          7 |          6 |          5 |          4 |          3 |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Now I need to find suitable intervals for each Item. For instance, in this case I want to find all intervals with a minimum duration of 3-days.

```
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| Item |  1_START   |   1_END    |  2_START   |   2_END    |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| A    | NaN        | NaN        | NaN        | NaN        |
| B    | 01/08/2020 | 03/08/2020 | 06/08/2020 | 08/08/2020 |
| C    | NaN        | NaN        | NaN        | NaN        |
| D    | 01/08/2020 | 07/08/2020 | NaN        | NaN        |
| E    | 01/08/2020 | NaN        | NaN        | NaN        |
+------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

In reality the data is 700+ columns wide and 1,000+ rows. How can I do this efficiently?